# MYSQL Database Design: How to store 3 Dimensional data for every user?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

To explain my issue I will use an illustration. Say I am a shop owner and I have my 'shop' MYSql database. I then have a table for all the customers of my shop and a table containing all the products I sell.

Along with saving the basic details of the customers (name, email etc) I also want to be able to save each individual basket they create. I can confidently use MYSql tables with 1D data, e.g. one row representing one user / product. How, though, can I store a variable amount of baskets, each containing a variable amount of products - for each user - in this shop database in an efficient way?

Any suggestions are appreciated, I am fairly new to MYSQL / Database design!

Thanks, Steve.

Comment: basic db theory: every column in a database is another "dimension", basically... if you want multiple baskets, then add a per-user basket ID field.

Comment: You should think in an other way: you have a table of baskets and one colum for their reference to clients. This reference is the client id.

Comment: Rows do not represent entities.  Entities are represented by values (their keys) while rows relate entities/values.  Peter Chen's paper `The Entity-Relationship Model : Toward a Unified View of Data` defined the concepts and should be required reading for database developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fully normalized design would have a basket table that has its own unique id and references the customer id.  This basket table could also have information about the basket, such as when it was created, if it was canceled or taken through to payment, etc.  Your DB would then also have a basket_products table that references the basket table's unique id, and the product's id, along with any information that you would have for that product when it was put in that basket.  This would allow for say temporary discounts, or special customer deals on that product at that time.

```
BASKET
id  autonum
customer_id  references customer.id
other info about the basket

BASKET_PRODUCTS (or PRODUCTS_IN_BASKET)
basket_id  references basket.id
product_id  references product.id
other info about the products as the are put in this basket (number purchased, price per, etc)
```

Comment: so in the BASKET_PRODUCTS table you would duplicate items if they are in multiple baskets? And would this scale reasonably to thousands of users with multiple baskets of 50 or so products each? Thanks mate!

Comment: Single or double digit multiples of 50000 rows are easily handled by MySQL running on modest hardware, provided that the right indexes are set up.  I agree with this answer.

Comment: Steve - yes, a DB has no problem dealing with millions of records in a table.  I have dealt with tables of up to over 4 billion records.  Eventually you will need to have some sort of archive or clean up process, but that is normal (geeky pun recognized) and true no matter what layout you choose.

Comment: Steve - by the way, since you say you are starting out in DB's, let me pass on a pet peeve of mine.  You may be already well aware of this, and if so, forgive me for saying it...  Choose a good naming standard for how you are going to name your tables and fields and stick with it.  It will go a long way towards making your db and your code more maintainable.